# Invalid child element MvcBuildViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have an **ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta** app and have set `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`

in the property group at the top of my csproj file. But my views are not being compiled. A closer look at the .csproj file shows a squiggly under the MvcBuildViews tag and when I hover over it, it says

> The element 'PropertyGroup'
>   in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'
>   has invalid child element
>   'MvcBuildViews' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.
>   List of possible elements expected:
>   'Property' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: In fact I was wrong, although Visual studio is complaining with the error described above. Setting <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews> is actually compiling the views.

Comment: Mine refuses to compile the views, I get a machineLevel definition error =(

Answer (score 2):

Many elements you define in the .config are not part of that schema, but still operate. It's the same way for MSBuild scripts.

Answer (score 0):

That's a custom property we include in the project files to compile views. It shouldn't cause any problems, since you can define your own properties (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4w159bs.aspx) in your project file.

For further detail, please refer to:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1506782.aspx?Error+invalid+child+element+MvcBuildViews+in+namespace

btw, this issue existed in 2009, but now is 2015, it still exists.